# Calculate thresholds of factor analysis output to classify data to 5 classes

Tags: classification, clustering, spss, factor-analysis, model-evaluation

Suppose that we calculate a composite indicator for some companies using Factor Analysis (FA) by combining five features to one output (calculate weights of input features). This is histogram of output:

[image]

We have five levels for company branches. Higher level means bigger branches with higher number of personals and capital. If we have a higher level of output based on our analysis, the Board of the company promotes this branch to higher level in real world. How can I classify my output (which is here between 0 and 200 - based on normalization technique that was used as pre-processing) to 5 levels to compare between model and current levels? The output for two-step clustering is here:

[image]
[image]

This clustering method classify performance of 100 as class 3!. Why do we have this behavior (same in k-means clustering)? What is best procedure for doing this?

Comment: I don't know SPSS but is the method you're using unsupervised? Bear in mind that most upsupervised cluster solutions do not create ordinal relationships based on the assigned cluster *number*. It's only with a post-hoc analysis that you can determine any ordinality based on the input features. So, cluster "3" may contain the highest values on the factor and cluster "5" may have the lowest. In other words, the numbers assigned to the cluster solutions are arbitrary.

Comment: @DJohnson. Thank you for your comment. That's true. This is an unsupervised method. What is your recommended method here? You are refering to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_analysis?

Comment: I don't have a recommended or better method since your current approach may be fine. I'm simply suggesting that you dig deeper into what your clusters *mean*. At that point, you should understand why cluster "3" captures the highest factor scores.

Comment: Let me amplify what I said yesterday. By "dig deeper" I mean running average, median or summed values (as appropriate) by cluster to *profile* what the clusters *mean*. In this way, you can understand why, e.g., cluster "3" has high values on the factor since the relative level of these summary statistics across the clusters create a *profile*. One easy heuristic is to *index* the cluster metrics to a grand or overall metric. Wide deviations (like an IQ score where 120+ or 80 or less) are indicative of features or behaviors representative (or not) of a cluster.

Comment: The histogram suggests to me that any classification will be fairly arbitrary. As others have pointed out, there is no guarantee even that distinctions between clusters will correspond to gaps on the histogram. Perhaps some application to follow is behind the urge to classify.

Comment: @DJohnson. Thanks. Question edited to new form. please add your discussion here as answer (or comment).

Answer (score 1):

Cluster analysis is designed for **multivariate** data.

There are a few methods for univariate data, but you would mostly use *more powerful* statistical approaches then (which won't work on multivariate data, unfortunately).

Because these methods are designed for multivariate data *and* multivariate data is not *ordered*, **the clusters are not sorted**.

It is a perfectly valid result if cluster 3 has a larger mean than cluster 5 **because the cluster id number is essentially random**.

Visualize your results. The clusters may look good on that bar chart - but might be useless. Instead, consider picking 4 thresholds by hand to split your data, based on the histogram!

Comment: Thank you for answer. I edited the question with more information. We have current levels (and calculated output) of companies in new form of question. In your proposed method (selecting thresholds using histogram) every small change of threshold can severely affect our levels.

Comment: Clustering will be even more heuristic, irreproducible etc. it is not meant to be used automatically.

Comment: So you think it is better to only use raw outputs?

Comment: *look* at the plot. It's 1 dimensional data, easy. Choose thresholds that are meaningful. Task completed.